# Error javascript only get first value data-href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-comments

I have a sample code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-comments" id="fb-comment" data-href="http://fb.com/t1" data-num-posts="3" data-width="590" ></div> 

<div class="fb-comments" id="fb-comment" data-href="http://fb.com/t2" data-num-posts="3" data-width="590" ></div>
```

And javascript:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId : 'xxx', // App ID
        channelUrl : 'xxx', // Channel File
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml : true // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
        var href = jQuery('.fb-comments').attr('data-href');
        alert(href);
    });
}
</script>
```

Error jquery only get first value is http://fb.com/t1, not get http://fb.com/t2

Comment: Use a `jQuery.each` loop to iterate over the elements

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/j8A3p/)

make use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to traverse to every element with class `fb-comments`

```
var href='';
jQuery('.fb-comments').each(function () {
    href += $(this).attr('data-href') + ' ';
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/4v8jK/1/)

or make use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

`href` is in the form of array using below code

```
var href= jQuery('.fb-comments').map(function(){
    return jQuery(this).attr('data-href');
});
console.log(href);
```

Comment: use .map() not run, it return value [object Object]

Comment: `.map()` crates array so to access array we `href[index]` eg. `href[0]` `href[1]` for accessing array values

Answer (score 0):

```
var thestring = '';

$('.fb-comments').each(function () {
    thestring += $(this).attr('data-href') + ' ';
});
```